# How can I specify heroku's MIME type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to play with the postgresql db on heroku which is used by my rails app, but `heroku pg` returns this error message:

```
 !    Please specify a version along with Heroku's API MIME type.
 For example, `Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3`.
```

What is Heroku's API MIME type? How can I specify the right value?

Comment: Post your logs as well

Comment: This was all the message I got.

Comment: I got this error when calling an endpoint of the heroku Api. I solved it by setting the correct [`accept`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#clients) header.

Answer (score 3):

This was due to the old version of heroku toolbelt used in cloud9. This error was gone after updating heroku cli with:

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

following the discussion in https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-update-heroku-cli/12074/10 .

Comment: I have the latest Heroku toolbelt and I still have this message when I run a rake task on Heroku, do you know what else it could be?

Comment: I use version 8.1.4. on Windows and c9. As far as I know I did not change anything other than the cli..

Comment: @JPG -- check out my answer below -- you might need to uninstall / remove the old version of heroku -- try 'which heroku' and see if it is using /usr/local/bin/heroku -- if not, it's not using the latest heroku toolbelt one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem -- there were 2 things I needed to do.
From: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

I needed to install the new Toolbelt.  Instructions are included on that link, and are platform dependent, so I won't include them here.  The other thing I needed to do, which I didn't realize at first after installing the toolbelt, was to make sure the heroku binary that was running was the one installed by the toolbelt.

if you run `which heroku`, it is supposed to return

> /usr/local/bin/heroku

If it doesn't, you will need to remove the other binary, or change your path.  In my case, I needed to do a `gem uninstall heroku` in addition to installing the toolbelt, then everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have encounter the same problem with yours.
And I have just use the command as follows:

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

It's also useless.
Finally I find I forgot configure **gem 'pg'** in group of production in Gerfile.Just like this.

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

and then run

```
bundle install
```

The problem will disappear.
At this time,no matter what commands such as **$heroku login**, **$heroku --version**,**$heroku create** you input ,there will shows nothing about erorr.

---

---

Answer (score 0):

for cloud 9 ide:

The command `wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh` did not work for me to correct MIME type error.  After running the command (without the q so I could see the full output) I noticed the following failure

> Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

My solution

1. from [Heroku support site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) instruction (Other installation methods, Standalone installation), I ran `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh` (as sudo). It installed into usr/local/lib/Heroku and the app disappeared from c9
   !
2. I copied the Heroku directory from usr/local/lib to usr/lib/ (`cp -r usr/loca/lib/Heroku usr/lib` ) and voila!
3. Heroku version now gives heroku/7.19.4 linux-x64 node-v11.3.0.  I think it was giving Heroku 3.23 before.  Looks to be working but if I run into any problems I will update (using wget command above) from this point. Hope this is of help to someone!